# como puedo usar la consola de laravel en un servidor remoto?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Soy nuevo en laravel y estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual necesito hacer un cron job, el problema es que no se que ruta debo dar,me gustaria saber como ejecutar comandos de artisan en un servidor remoto, y que programas debo utilizar, cualquier respuesta me sera de mucha ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Todo está en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling , en cuanto a ejecutarlo de un servidor a otro, no me queda claro lo que quieres hacer, ¿es enviar el comando desde otro servidor? ejecutar el cron en otro servidor? Qué tipo de servidores son?

Comment: hola shaz, veras, solo he ejecutado comandos de artisan en local, pero no se como hacerlo si el proyecto esta en el servidor,  y quiero conocer la ruta exacta del proyecto porque debo usarla para el cron job

Comment: Si entiendo bien, ¿lo que quieres es simplemente configurar el cron en el servidor "remoto" para que funcione como en local?

Comment: si, utilizando  por ejemplo la ruta "* * * * * php /Users/MyUser/dev/project/artisan schedule:run" he intentado con todas las que me da el servidor y me lanza el error "errors in crontab file, can't install." ,como habras notado soy bastante novato en laravel, es mi primer proyecto, y no se como obtener la raiz ya que no se como conseguir la consola en remoto, hay algun programa o guia que explique bien como hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejecutar comandos de artisan en local o en un servidor remoto debería ser similar, asumiendo que estés trabajando con ambientes similares y que tengas los permisos adecuados para ejecutar php o artisan desde la línea de comando.

Más información sobre los cron de Laravel en su documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling

---

Si necesitas saber la ruta base de tu proyecto, puedes imprimirla y verla rápidamente con el helper `base_path()`, aquí encontrarás su documentación respectiva: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-base-path

Comment: bien, entonces se puede acceder al servidor remoto mediante la consola en local no?, me enfocare en eso, "base_path" servira para el cron asi la ejecute en local?, ya que en el servidor el orden de las carpetas es muy distinto, una cosas que he notado es que parece que laravel no ha sido instalado en el servidor, crees que esto tambien cause problemas?

Comment: base_path() es solo un atajo rápido para que obtengas "visualmente" la ruta y la copies en tu archivo de cron. Todo esto házlo en el servidor remoto.

Comment: No sé como estés instalando Laravel en tu servidor "remoto" ni qué sistema operativo tiene dicho servidor.

Comment: hola @Shaz, si el servidor no tiene instalado composer, ni se ha instalado laravel de la forma "ortodoxa", es decir, el laravel que aqui se usa es un proyecto realizado en local que luego se subio al servidor, esto afectaria a la hora de realizar los cron jobs?

Comment: No, no tiene nada que ver, al menos normalmente. Si Laravel funciona, deberían funcionar los cron jobs.